# Print a part of text over and over when matched found

Tags: python, string

I got a JSON file looking document and I want to print it by each separate line.

```
ars = [{"TAX_NO": "101", "STATE": "NY", "TAX_RATE": "0.077306618"}, {"TAX_NO": "102", "STATE": "NH", "TAX_RATE": "0"}, {"TAX_NO": "103", "STATE": "LA", "TAX_RATE": "0.079650877"}, {"TAX_NO": "104", "STATE": "HI", "TAX_RATE": "0.04"}, {"TAX_NO": "105", "STATE": "TX", "TAX_RATE": "0.07117549"}, {"TAX_NO": "106", "STATE": "MP", "TAX_RATE": "0"}, {"TAX_NO": "107", "STATE": "MH", "TAX_RATE": "0"}, {"TAX_NO": "108", "STATE": "GA", "TAX_RATE": "0.067139394"}, {"TAX_NO": "109", "STATE": "AS", "TAX_RATE": "0"}, {"TAX_NO": "110", "STATE": "VI", "TAX_RATE": "0.04"}, {"TAX_NO": "111", "STATE": "MS", "TAX_RATE": "0.070011099"}, {"TAX_NO": "112", "STATE": "MA", "TAX_RATE": "0.05"}, {"TAX_NO": "113", "STATE": "KY", "TAX_RATE": "0.06"}, {"TAX_NO": "114", "STATE": "IA", "TAX_RATE": "0.058971444"}, {"TAX_NO": "115", "STATE": "MI", "TAX_RATE": "0.06"}, {"TAX_NO": "116", "STATE": "AZ", "TAX_RATE": "0.069162196"}, {"TAX_NO": "117", "STATE": "PW", "TAX_RATE": "0"]'

# I have a very long JSON text and I want to print part of the text each time when it matches to  ",}". So basically I'm looking at the below text separately in each line.
# Is there a way I can do that? Thanks in advance.
[{"TAX_NO": "101", "STATE": "NY", "TAX_RATE": "0.077306618"},
{"TAX_NO": "102", "STATE": "NH", "TAX_RATE": "0"},
{"TAX_NO": "103", "STATE": "LA", "TAX_RATE": "0.079650877"},
{"TAX_NO": "104", "STATE": "HI", "TAX_RATE": "0.04"},
{"TAX_NO": "107", "STATE": "MH", "TAX_RATE": "0"}, 
{"TAX_NO": "108", "STATE": "GA", "TAX_RATE": "0.067139394"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Unnecessarily complicated method:

```
import json

arsout = json.dumps(ars)
print(arsout .replace("}, {", "},\n{"))
```

Output:

```
[{"TAX_NO": "101", "STATE": "NY", "TAX_RATE": "0.077306618"},
{"TAX_NO": "102", "STATE": "NH", "TAX_RATE": "0"},
{"TAX_NO": "103", "STATE": "LA", "TAX_RATE": "0.079650877"},
{"TAX_NO": "104", "STATE": "HI", "TAX_RATE": "0.04"},
{"TAX_NO": "105", "STATE": "TX", "TAX_RATE": "0.07117549"},
{"TAX_NO": "106", "STATE": "MP", "TAX_RATE": "0"},
{"TAX_NO": "107", "STATE": "MH", "TAX_RATE": "0"},
{"TAX_NO": "108", "STATE": "GA", "TAX_RATE": "0.067139394"},
{"TAX_NO": "109", "STATE": "AS", "TAX_RATE": "0"},
{"TAX_NO": "110", "STATE": "VI", "TAX_RATE": "0.04"},
{"TAX_NO": "111", "STATE": "MS", "TAX_RATE": "0.070011099"},
{"TAX_NO": "112", "STATE": "MA", "TAX_RATE": "0.05"},
{"TAX_NO": "113", "STATE": "KY", "TAX_RATE": "0.06"},
{"TAX_NO": "114", "STATE": "IA", "TAX_RATE": "0.058971444"},
{"TAX_NO": "115", "STATE": "MI", "TAX_RATE": "0.06"},
{"TAX_NO": "116", "STATE": "AZ", "TAX_RATE": "0.069162196"},
{"TAX_NO": "117", "STATE": "PW", "TAX_RATE": "0"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

If `ars` is a list of dicionaries, you could try:

```
ars = [{"TAX_NO": "101", "STATE": "NY", "TAX_RATE": "0.077306618"}, {"TAX_NO": "102", "STATE": "NH", "TAX_RATE": "0"}, {"TAX_NO": "103", "STATE": "LA", "TAX_RATE": "0.079650877"}, {"TAX_NO": "104", "STATE": "HI", "TAX_RATE": "0.04"}, {"TAX_NO": "105", "STATE": "TX", "TAX_RATE": "0.07117549"}, {"TAX_NO": "106", "STATE": "MP", "TAX_RATE": "0"}, {"TAX_NO": "107", "STATE": "MH", "TAX_RATE": "0"}, {"TAX_NO": "108", "STATE": "GA", "TAX_RATE": "0.067139394"}, {"TAX_NO": "109", "STATE": "AS", "TAX_RATE": "0"}, {"TAX_NO": "110", "STATE": "VI", "TAX_RATE": "0.04"}, {"TAX_NO": "111", "STATE": "MS", "TAX_RATE": "0.070011099"}, {"TAX_NO": "112", "STATE": "MA", "TAX_RATE": "0.05"}, {"TAX_NO": "113", "STATE": "KY", "TAX_RATE": "0.06"}, {"TAX_NO": "114", "STATE": "IA", "TAX_RATE": "0.058971444"}, {"TAX_NO": "115", "STATE": "MI", "TAX_RATE": "0.06"}, {"TAX_NO": "116", "STATE": "AZ", "TAX_RATE": "0.069162196"}, {"TAX_NO": "117", "STATE": "PW", "TAX_RATE": "0"}]

for i in ars:
    print(i)
```

If it is a string and you want to print each dicitonarie as type string you could try this:

```
ars = '[{"TAX_NO": "101", "STATE": "NY", "TAX_RATE": "0.077306618"}, {"TAX_NO": "102", "STATE": "NH", "TAX_RATE": "0"}, {"TAX_NO": "103", "STATE": "LA", "TAX_RATE": "0.079650877"}, {"TAX_NO": "104", "STATE": "HI", "TAX_RATE": "0.04"}, {"TAX_NO": "105", "STATE": "TX", "TAX_RATE": "0.07117549"}, {"TAX_NO": "106", "STATE": "MP", "TAX_RATE": "0"}, {"TAX_NO": "107", "STATE": "MH", "TAX_RATE": "0"}, {"TAX_NO": "108", "STATE": "GA", "TAX_RATE": "0.067139394"}, {"TAX_NO": "109", "STATE": "AS", "TAX_RATE": "0"}, {"TAX_NO": "110", "STATE": "VI", "TAX_RATE": "0.04"}, {"TAX_NO": "111", "STATE": "MS", "TAX_RATE": "0.070011099"}, {"TAX_NO": "112", "STATE": "MA", "TAX_RATE": "0.05"}, {"TAX_NO": "113", "STATE": "KY", "TAX_RATE": "0.06"}, {"TAX_NO": "114", "STATE": "IA", "TAX_RATE": "0.058971444"}, {"TAX_NO": "115", "STATE": "MI", "TAX_RATE": "0.06"}, {"TAX_NO": "116", "STATE": "AZ", "TAX_RATE": "0.069162196"}, {"TAX_NO": "117", "STATE": "PW", "TAX_RATE": "0"]'
for i in ars[1:len(ars)-2].split('}, '):
    print(i+'}, ','\n')
```

And if it is a string and you want to print each dictionary as type dictionary, you could try this:

```
import ast
ars = '[{"TAX_NO": "101", "STATE": "NY", "TAX_RATE": "0.077306618"}, {"TAX_NO": "102", "STATE": "NH", "TAX_RATE": "0"}, {"TAX_NO": "103", "STATE": "LA", "TAX_RATE": "0.079650877"}, {"TAX_NO": "104", "STATE": "HI", "TAX_RATE": "0.04"}, {"TAX_NO": "105", "STATE": "TX", "TAX_RATE": "0.07117549"}, {"TAX_NO": "106", "STATE": "MP", "TAX_RATE": "0"}, {"TAX_NO": "107", "STATE": "MH", "TAX_RATE": "0"}, {"TAX_NO": "108", "STATE": "GA", "TAX_RATE": "0.067139394"}, {"TAX_NO": "109", "STATE": "AS", "TAX_RATE": "0"}, {"TAX_NO": "110", "STATE": "VI", "TAX_RATE": "0.04"}, {"TAX_NO": "111", "STATE": "MS", "TAX_RATE": "0.070011099"}, {"TAX_NO": "112", "STATE": "MA", "TAX_RATE": "0.05"}, {"TAX_NO": "113", "STATE": "KY", "TAX_RATE": "0.06"}, {"TAX_NO": "114", "STATE": "IA", "TAX_RATE": "0.058971444"}, {"TAX_NO": "115", "STATE": "MI", "TAX_RATE": "0.06"}, {"TAX_NO": "116", "STATE": "AZ", "TAX_RATE": "0.069162196"}, {"TAX_NO": "117", "STATE": "PW", "TAX_RATE": "0"}]'

for i in ars[1:len(ars)-2].split('}, '):
    print(ast.literal_eval(str(i+'}')))
```

Output of all options is the same, only varies the type of each dictionary(`str` or `dict`):

```
{'TAX_NO': '101', 'STATE': 'NY', 'TAX_RATE': '0.077306618'} ,
{'TAX_NO': '102', 'STATE': 'NH', 'TAX_RATE': '0'} ,
{'TAX_NO': '103', 'STATE': 'LA', 'TAX_RATE': '0.079650877'} ,
{'TAX_NO': '104', 'STATE': 'HI', 'TAX_RATE': '0.04'} ,
{'TAX_NO': '105', 'STATE': 'TX', 'TAX_RATE': '0.07117549'} ,
{'TAX_NO': '106', 'STATE': 'MP', 'TAX_RATE': '0'} ,
{'TAX_NO': '107', 'STATE': 'MH', 'TAX_RATE': '0'} ,
{'TAX_NO': '108', 'STATE': 'GA', 'TAX_RATE': '0.067139394'} ,
{'TAX_NO': '109', 'STATE': 'AS', 'TAX_RATE': '0'} ,
{'TAX_NO': '110', 'STATE': 'VI', 'TAX_RATE': '0.04'} ,
{'TAX_NO': '111', 'STATE': 'MS', 'TAX_RATE': '0.070011099'} ,
{'TAX_NO': '112', 'STATE': 'MA', 'TAX_RATE': '0.05'} ,
{'TAX_NO': '113', 'STATE': 'KY', 'TAX_RATE': '0.06'} ,
{'TAX_NO': '114', 'STATE': 'IA', 'TAX_RATE': '0.058971444'} ,
{'TAX_NO': '115', 'STATE': 'MI', 'TAX_RATE': '0.06'} ,
{'TAX_NO': '116', 'STATE': 'AZ', 'TAX_RATE': '0.069162196'} ,
{'TAX_NO': '117', 'STATE': 'PW', 'TAX_RATE': '0'}
```

Also be careful because the last element of ars you provided, is `{"TAX_NO": "117", "STATE": "PW", "TAX_RATE": "0"]'`, and as you can see, it's missing the last bracket, and that will resutl in errors

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad it helps you @rra, you might consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it maybe :)?